# Make Scratch stop asking to save a file before closing a file

Tags: code

How can I make Scratch stop asking to save before closing a file, while I make no changes? This happens when I did Preferences > Behavior > radio button off 'Save files when changed'.
Thank-you!

Answer (score 2):

This bug is already fixed in trunk (the current developement branch of Scratch). 
See for more details: https://code.launchpad.net/~vishalrao/scratch/fix-1547327/+merge/317063

The only thing to do for you now is to wait for the new Scratch update to be released.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug and I saw something on the elementary Slack channel about this so I believe it is being looked at.